# Video not working

Tags: html

I have a site with video playing option, which works fine in local. But, when I uploaded the site to the server to run online, the video is not working.
The code I used is,

```
<video class="video-play" controls="">
      <source src="videoname.flv" type="video/flv">
      <source src="videoname.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="videoname.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="videoname.ogv" type="video/ogg">
      Video not playing? <a href="videoname.mp4">Download file</a> instead.
</video>
```

What did I miss??

Comment: check path src of the video?

Comment: @dippas, I checked that, "The source path is correct".

Answer (score 1):

All video files must reside in the same directory as your HTML file, as defined by `src` attribute of `source` tag in your case.

Also make sure the files are completely uploaded, i.e. not partially.

**EDIT:**

Try to make sure your video file names does not contain spaces, some old web server configurations got confused by that. Also check for non-English alphabets in the file names, for the same reason.

Comment: Yes, @bodi0. The video files are in the exact location of, where the html file is located. Also, the videos are fully uploaded.

Comment: the file name is "kanchisaree.flv" and the same name for other formats too.